# Trying to retrieve data from a template in a website using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm stumped on how to get data from a template from a particular site. The url to the site is: http://www.dnainfo.com/chicago/2013-chicago-murders/timeline?mon=1

, with the month starting at January. In the source the template is shown as: id="homicide_template". So, I use the below code to get that particular template w/ its elements:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url =  urllib2.urlopen('http://dnainfo.com/chicago/2013-chicago-murders/timeline?mon=1')
html = url.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
site_template = soup.find(id="homicide_template")

print site_template
```

I'm not sure how I can get the data from Age, Race, Cause, Neighborhood, and Time from the template for each person and save them to a database or .csv file. I'm just starting to use these modules (urllib2 and BeautifulSoup 4). So, any help/direction is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is created dynamically, so you can't use just beautifulsoup to parse it.  You are going to need something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to grab the rendered webpage.  You can do that like:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

url = 'http://dnainfo.com/chicago/2013-chicago-murders/timeline?mon=1'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Doing some quick inspection it looks like the page is not going to be super friendly to parse. However, I noticed that every entry has a `<div class="well well-small">` right after the `<div>` that contains the name (there is probably some better tag to go off of that I'm not noticing). Knowing this, you can do something like:

```
dudes = []
for dude in soup.find_all('div', 'well well-small'):
    dude_info = {}
    dude_info['Name'] = dude.parent['id']
    dude_info['Age'] = dude.find('div', 'age meta').contents[1]
    dude_info['Race'] = dude.find('div', 'race meta').contents[1]
    dude_info['Cause'] = dude.find('div', 'cause meta').contents[1]
    dude_info['Neighborhood'] = dude.find('div', 'neighborhood meta').contents[1]
    dude_info['Time'] = dude.find('div', 'time meta').contents[-1].next_element

    dudes.append(dude_info)
```